# iOS - viewDidUnload not called, but didReceiveMemoryWarning is called

Tags: ios, memory-management, didreceivememorywarning, viewdidunload

Trying to hunt down the cause of crashing on certain devices. I am noticing that my view controllers are receiving `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, but NOT `viewDidUnload`. And according to Apple:

> you would not use didReceiveMemoryWarning to release references to view objects, you might use it to release any view-related data structures that you did not already release in your viewDidUnload method. (The view objects themselves should always be released in the viewDidUnload method.)

So,

A: Why is `viewDidUnload` not called? I can't remove my view objects here if it is never called.

B: If I'm not supposed to remove my view objects in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, where else would I do this?

C: Using ARC, should I still need to remove view objects, set arrays to nil, etc?

Comment: I find it unlikely your crash is caused by not removing views and such. You should check using Instruments that running out of memory is causing the crashes.

Comment: @MaxGabriel I am running out of memory. But one of my view controllers has a lot of images. So when I get a warning I can free up memory be removing them.

Answer (score 2):

As the other mentioned `viewDidUnload:` is deprecated in iOS 6. But as additional information you should know, that it is seldom necessary to unload a `UIView` since iOS 6 is doing its magic thingie in the background -it is destroying the bitmap layer of the backing `CALayer` of the view (which is by far the biggest "part" of a `UIView`). If the view is needed again iOS will call `drawRect:` where you compose your view and everything will be ok.

For more information read this great article of Joe Conway: [ViewController lifecycle in iOS 6](http://thejoeconwayblog.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/view-controller-lifecycle-in-ios-6/)

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidUnload` is deprecated in iOS6. You "can" remove views in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` if you think it is necessary, but it is left up to you.

This thread may help as well.

[viewDidUnload no longer called in ios6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509102/viewdidunload-no-longer-called-in-ios6)

Comment: holy crap, I didn't know this. Doesn't that make any app that was cleaning up views in viewDidUnload highly susceptible to crashing when getting memory warnings?

Comment: And if the view doesn't get unloaded, how does the view controller know to reload the view? I can remove the image views in didReceiveMemoryWarning, but now they are gone when I go back to that view controller

Comment: I am not hundred percent, but my understanding is that if you set `self.view = nil`, on next access to the view, `viewDidLoad` will be called. BTW, if you are building your subviews as `IBOutlet`, best practice seems to declare them as `weak` properties, so that when you set `self.view = nil` all the subviews will be released too.

Answer (score 0):

`didReceiveMemoryWarning` is specifically targeted not to the unloading of a view, but rather for the view controller to *release objects which can easily be recreated* (i.e. UIIamges and the like).  You should not release objects in your view unless they can easily be recreated as necessary.